# layoutInflater crash in fragment java android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I tried different solutions but continuously when I start the application I receive a layout error, thank you all for the help.

Adapter :

```
public class Adattatore_Main extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public final int TYPE_MOVIE = 0;
    public final int TYPE_LOAD = 1;
    Context context;
    List<Variabili_Main> movies;
    OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener;
    boolean isLoading = false, isMoreDataAvailable = true;

    /*
    * isLoading - to set the remote loading and complete status to fix back to back load more call
    * isMoreDataAvailable - to set whether more data from server available or not.
    * It will prevent useless load more request even after all the server data loaded
    * */


    public Adattatore_Main(Context context, List<Variabili_Main> movies) {
        this.context = context;
        this.movies = movies;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if(viewType==TYPE_MOVIE){
            return new MovieHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contenitore_post, parent, false));
        }else{
            return new LoadHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.caricamento, parent, false));
        }
    }
```

Crash here :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Main Activity :

```
public class Main_Post extends Fragment {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Variabili_Main> movies;
    Adattatore_Main adapter;
    Api api;
    String TAG = "MainActivity - ";
    Context context;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activitymain_post, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new Adattatore_Main(context, movies);
        adapter.setLoadMoreListener(new Adattatore_Main.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {

                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int index = movies.size() - 1;
                        loadMore(index);
                    }
                });
                //Calling loadMore function in Runnable to fix the
                // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling error
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalLineDecorator(2));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        api = ServiceGenerator.createService(Api.class);
        load(0);
        return view;
    }
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Debug :

```
                                     --------- beginning of crash
11-05 14:44:24.241 659-659/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs, PID: 659
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:232)
                                                                                        at com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs.Adattatore_Main.onCreateViewHolder(Adattatore_Main.java:76)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5464)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4689)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4599)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1988)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1384)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3003)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2600)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1560)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
11-05 14:44:24.241 659-659/com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)


                                                                                    --------- beginning of system
```

This is a part of code, if you need more code i'm here. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you never initialize `context` in `Main_Post`, so it's null when you instantiate `Adattatore_Main`. It looks like the line it's crashing on is unnecessary anyway, since you're not using `inflater` anywhere. Also, please include the stack trace when you want help debugging a crash.

Comment: I attached the debug

Comment: the `context` in your fragment is never initialized , so use `getActivity()` to get context in fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inflate layout before getting system layout inflating permission. You just change in you code. Other think if you can see your `onCreateView()` method then you pass null context object when you initialize your adapter object that's why your recycler view receive null context. You need to initialize your context before you pass in your adapter object. i hope this will solve your problem

```
context = getActivity();
adapter = new Adattatore_Main(context, movies);
```

Then after change your below code on your adapter

```
LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater = inflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_row, parent ,false);
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Solved! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

**write**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getcontext());
```

**update**

it seems that you did not pass context in adapter. if you need to use any context in fragment then use getActivity(). it will solve your context initialization problem.